# Passenger not working with SSL on Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, http-status-code-403

I have a Rails app running on Passenger; It works as expected over unencrypted connections. I also have a working Apache SSL setup; I can access any static file available via http with https. When I try to access the Rails app via https, I get a 403 error (Directory index forbidden by rule). Turning on indexes for the directory simply causes Apache to display an index. I do have `+ExecCGI` set for the appropriate directory in the SSL version of the VirtualHost directive.

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm overlooking. I'm just not sure where I need to be looking.

Answer (score 0):

There were domain-wide VirtualHost directives for each of SSL and non-SSL. The non-SSL version contained a RailsBaseURI directive, while the SSL version did not. Passenger requires the RailsBaseURI directive to work.